# Secure Folder in iOS swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am creating custom folder in iPhone device by using my native iOS app. It is creating successfully.But I want to set a password for that Folder for securing Folder's data. How can I set the password for that folder in iOS swift?

```
var paths: [Any] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: String = paths[0] as? String ?? ""
// Get documents folder
let dataPath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("/MyFolder").absoluteString
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath) {
    try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
}
```

Comment: Securing the data from where?  Access from inside or outside the app?

Comment: Folder data access from inside the app

Comment: There isn't a way to 'set a password' you are going to have to develop that idea yourself and it will depend entirely on how you app is designed and functions.